# Javascript al cargar la página o al pulsar una tecla

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

Tengo este código que realiza su función cuando se pulsa una tecla con *.onkeyup* y funciona correctamente.

```
    function compile() {
  var html = document.getElementById("html");
  var css = document.getElementById("css");
  var js = document.getElementById("js");
  var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

  document.body.onkeyup = function() {
    code.open();
    code.writeln(
      html.value +
        "<style>" +
        css.value +
        "</style>" +
        "<script>" +
        js.value +
        "</script>"
    );
    code.close();
  };
}

compile();
```

Y si quisiera que además de esto **hiciera lo mismo también al cargar la página** por primera vez?
Osea una especie de *.onkeyup or .onload*(en el caso de ser así)

Gracias. Mis conocimientos de Javascript son casi nulos si las explicaciones pueden ser simples mejor.

Comment: Tienes que escapar la barra de </script> dentro de la función keyup: <\/script>. Para que lance la función en el body pones algo así en el html: <body onload="compile()">

Comment: Creo que más o menos entiendo lo que dices. Pero este código que pongo está en un archivo aparte, no con el <body> y demás. Hay alguna forma de hacer lo que comentas pero dentro de este mismo archivo? Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Podrías usar jQuery que tiene una función que te permite ejecutar lo que quieras una vez se ha cargado el html: $(document).ready

Comment: Me viene grande.Con lo fácil que sería un document.body.onkeyup || .onload o algo así...El asco que le estoy cojiendo a este lenguaje es importante. Gracias de nuevo ;)

Comment: Añadir jQuery cuesta muy poco pero si quieres probar con hacer un window.onload en lugar de document.body.onload por ver si te vale, adelante

Comment: creo que puedes hacer algo como esto: https://gomakethings.com/listening-to-multiple-events-in-vanilla-js/

Comment: Ahora le echo un ojo.Gracias

Comment: Tambíen podrían plantear el problema de otra forma. Ya que el código se me ejecuta al pulsar un tecla, hay alguna forma de simular pulsar una tecla y añadir ese código al del ejemplo que he compartido?

Comment: puedes agregar la funcion al onload `window.onload = function() {
  compile();
};` o puedes ejecutarlo por listener `window.addEventListener('load', compile);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede cambiar `document.body.onkeyup = function() {` de la función `compile` por el atributo `onkeyup`, de esta manera `<body onkeyup=compile()`. Luego poner lo mismo en el atributo `onload`.

```
<body onload="compile()" onkeyup=compile()>
```

De esta manera, en la función `compile` no se define la función para teclear o cargar al inicio, sino que `compile` es la función que se ejecuta al hacer una de esas dos cosas, y está definido en los atributos de la etiqueta `body`.

Con respecto al `iframe`, es probable que no se pueda modificar su contenido a causa del dominio cruzado. Yo recomendaría añadir elementos mediante `createElement` y `appendChild` en vez de crear un *string HTML*.

```
var código = document.createElement("script")
código.innerHTML = js.value
iframe_head.appendChild(código)
```

Código:

```js
function compile()
{
 var html = document.getElementById("html")
 var css = document.getElementById("css")
 var js = document.getElementById("js")
 var code = document.getElementById("code")
 code.innerHTML=[html.value,css.value,js.value].join(" ")
}
```

```html
<body onload="compile()" onkeyup=compile()>
 <textarea id="html">a</textarea>
 <textarea id="css" >b</textarea>
 <textarea id="js" >c</textarea>
 <div id="code"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias por un respuesta tan detallada. En breve la pruebo. Actualmente he resuelto el problema con un: setTimeout(compile, 1000); ya que así me ejecuta el código cada segundo cosa que también me sirve aunque es una chapuza comparado con la solución que propones.

Comment: Es mejor no mezclar el javascript con el HTML, me gusta más la solucion que propone @JackNavaRow en su comentario